# Is there a way to clear NX Cloud cache?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nomachine-nx

I know I can clear nx cache with `nx reset` but is there a way to clear the NX Cloud cache?

I could not find a command or an option in their GUI that would enable this.

Comment: also needed this feature

Comment: Hi Felipe, did you find a way to clear the remote cache? I have searched everywhere but also can't seem to find a way to clear it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to remove the cache:

1. You can send an email at cloud-support@nrwl.io with that link and they can remove it.
2. You should also be able to delete your workspace through the UI which will remove your data.

For the second way:

- Log into the: https://nx.app/ with the account you have the workspace.
- Click on your avatar (top, right) and select **Connect a workspace**:

[image]

- Enable the checkbox "I already have an access token", place your token and click and connect:
- Now you are able to delete your workspace and the nxCloud cache links will be no longer available.

[image]